# Creating SHA-2 certificate using keychain assistant

Tags: macos, mojave, keychain, certificate, ssl

I am trying to enable https on my localhost (for testing).  Using Keychain Assistant, I have created both a self-signed CA and a certificate issued by that same CA.  I have enabled trust on the CA in Keychain Assistant. I have placed the certificate files in my MAMP folder and have updated both the httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf files.  When I access my local website using Safari, I get a message warning me that certificate is not trusted and a link to instructions on how to trust the certificate via Keychain Assistant.

I thought the purpose of setting trust on the CA was to not need to explicitly trust the certificates it issues.  I came across the following while trying to understand the issue.

[Why does iOS 13 not trust my own Root CA?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371725/why-does-ios-13-not-trust-my-own-root-ca)

It states that the hash must now be SHA-2 rather than SHA-1.  When I review the certificate info, its fingerprint appears to be using SHA-1.  I cannot figure out how to create an SHA-2 certificate using Keyboard Assistant.

Can anyone tell me where this hidden capability lies?  Or did Apple create a certificate requirement that its own tool cannot comply with?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was just my misunderstanding of how to read the certificate info and the various SHA algorithms.  I saw SHA-1 and SHA-256.   I did not realize the latter was a SHA-2 variant.  Apologies for any confusion this question may have caused.